# How do we deal with answers by customer support that basically don't answer the question?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251085/tata-docomo-photon-3g-not-working-on-12-04-lts) question today, this has been answered by someone who is presumably a customer support person for the company. I don't think there's anything wrong with this as long as it answers the question but in this case it's basically a message like we're sorry for your problem please call this phone number.

I flagged this for moderators attention but I'm not sure if it should be categorized as spam or not. What is the best course of action that should be taken for such questions?

Comment: I think flagging and downvoting should be done. This should be a comment, if added at all, and not as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have converted it to a comment and have left the poster a message. I don't think this is spam (the intention seems helpful) but you were otherwise right.

It's not an answer so it doesn't belong in the answers section.

Comment: How do you know it isn't spam or a scam?  Is this something we need to worry about?

Comment: @Seth A fair question and it is something you have to be aware of. In this case I just bundled the number into Google and it told me it was their real phone number.

Comment: Ah, very good way of testing it.

Comment: Call a toll free number? no! Customers are likely already aware of numbers to contact customer support (on the product package, or product webpage) and came here for more than that. Plus the user is unregistered and has made no customization, other than dropping the website on the profile.

Comment: @EliahKagan Tata Photon is an Indian company. Why would it be an number for the United States?

Comment: @Oli Apparently, I am mistaken; multiple numbers with that many digits are [listed here](http://www.tatadocomo.com/service-centers.aspx), so it is not an error.

Comment: @mateo_salta Indian customer support is extremely unhelpful and people do not contact them first. It is much easier to get the problem solved by manually debugging and working it out than spending 10 mins on hold and another 5 minutes trying to convince the executive that you are actually who you say, you are. Also, if a company is trying to help customers across different platforms, why is it a problem ? This particular comment might not be very helpful, but generally.